# My website's wp-admin redirects to another website's wp-admin after pointing the site url to a subdirectiory

Tags: wp-admin

*** DETAILS THAT LEAD UP TO MY PROBLEM  ***

I'm familiar with WP's Giving WordPress its own Directory in codex.

I am experimenting on my personal website, [erons-expressions.com](http://www.erons-expressions.com) with redirecting to different sub-directories. Originally I loaded WordPress files into its own /wordpress sub-directory and was successful with redirecting my site to it.

I'm working on a redesign for a non-profit ([wecareabilene.org](http://www.wecareabilene.org)) and will be using WP. They are a separate hosted account with their own wp-admin and I will need to use this method of redirecting for their site to different sub-directories through out the year.

As their website is currently live, I was experimenting with my own personal website to make sure I could redirect to multiple sub-directories successfully.

Since their site is already WP based, I placed all the non-profit's WP files into its own sub-directory (/CCC_Site) in my website's root folder.

I copied and pasted that sub-directory's .htaccess and index.php pages into my root.

I updated the index.php page with the update: require('./CCC_Site/wp-blog-header.php');

I changed my personal wp-admin site address to the /CCC_Site sub-directory.

Now if you go to my site, you will see that my website url is showing the contents of what is on the CCC_Site sub-directory, which is exactly what I'd hoped for.

*** MY PROBLEM ***

When I try to go to my website's wp-admin by typing erons-expressions.com/wp-admin I am redirected to wecareabilene.org/wp-admin. Since I now apparently don't have access to my personal website's wp-admin, I can't change its site url setting to get back to my site's original files.

Any ideas or thoughts or troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're question has a lot of irrelevant extra info.  The clients existing local site has nothing to do with this as I read it.  

Did you update your wp_home and wp_siteurl in the database or via define in wp-config?

Comment: I updated it in the general settings of my dashboard

Comment: What is the relationship between the two sites?

Comment: Other than I have one inside the other, nothing. One is my personal site, the other is a client's. The client's files are inside a sub-directory of my site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having trouble following your question.

You say you're familiar with giving WP it's own directory, but I think you may be confusing  installing a second WordPress install in a separate sub-directory with giving WordPress it's own sub-directory.

Possible file structures:

Single site:

```
/index.php (and all the rest of wordpress installed at root)
```

Multiple sites on a server:

```
/index.php
/wp-????? (a complete wordpress site, all your wp-???.php files, wp-content, wp-admin, wp-include, etc)
/second_site/index.php
/second_site/wp-?????
/third_site/index.php
/third_site/wp-?????
```

None of the above is giving WP it's own sub-directory.

```
/index.php
/wp-????? (a complete wordpress site, all your wp-???.php files, wp-content, wp-admin, wp-include, etc)
/second_site/index.php
/second_site/wordpress/wp-?????
/third_site/index.php
/third_site/wp-?????
```

In your web panel you'll point a domain at /second_site and a different domain at /third_site or you should be able to get to those sites as:
domain.com/second_site/

Does that help?

Comment: I've discovered my problem and rectified it. The new sub-directory I'd created (/CCC_Site) still had its wp_config listing that site's info instead of my personal site.